# How to use CSS make row1 keep center, row2 dock to bottom?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, grid

I want it Layout like the following, in 3 different size devices.

I'm new to CSS. It would be even better if it can be implemented with new layout technologies such as flexbox or grid.

```
                     -----------------
                     |               |
-----------------    |               |   
|               |    |               |    
|               |    |               |    -----------------
|               |    |               |    |               |
|<div>row1</div>|    |<div>row1</div>|    |<div>row1</div>|
|               |    |               |    |               |
|               |    |               |    |<div>row2</div>|
|               |    |               |    -----------------
|<div>row2</div>|    |               |    
-----------------    |               |
                     |<div>row2</div>|
                     -----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I use "position:absolute" for bottom paragraph. but make sure the parent div has "position: relative"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .mom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightseagreen;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  p {
    background: gold;
    width: 90%;
  }
 
  .sink {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="mom">
    <p class="center">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p class="sink">This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This second snippet is more dynamic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .mom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 90px;
    width: 40vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background: lightseagreen;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  p {
    background: gold;
    min-width: 90px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .sink {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="mom">
    <p class="center">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p class="sink">This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```